# How disable multipart upload so sync matches the md5sum of local and remote file in s3cmd

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, s3cmd

How disable multipart upload so sync matches the md5sum of local and remote file in s3cmd.
When I upload a large file, s3cmd separates the file into parts. The eTag on Amazon S3 is the last part of the multipart. How can I preserve the file uploaded with the md5sum of the local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually calculate and send (save) md5sum of the whole object in the custom HTTP header. You can add any HTTP header when you send PUT request, and you will get the same header and value for the next GET or HEAD requests.
We use this feature in our project [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs), to save md5sum of the stored object and then compare the hash with the cached object to avoid re-downloading local files.

Hope this information helps you !

Comment: so you don't use the sync at all in s3cmd? Just calculate the md5sum and put the file passing the x- metatags in Amazon S3?

Comment: yes, we don't use s3cmd. You are right, you can PUT any value to x-meta tags and you will get that when you next time access this object.